# IIS + PHP - Cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, iis

I'm with a big problem here.
I'm integrating an interface I've done using Codeigniter with an external Mysql Database.
The thing is that I'm getting `"Cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication"` error.
Yes, I've looked over the internet and found steps to solve it once we have admin rights to the database. The thing is that I have a ready-only access.

Can I do something to connect to this database?
Just to let you know, I'm not using a Linux Server, I'm using a Windows Server with IIS, and to be honest, I'm not very used to it.

These are the parameters I'm using to try to connect:

```
$db['otrs']['hostname'] = 'test.test.lan';
$db['otrs']['username'] = 'otrs';
$db['otrs']['password'] = 'otrs';
$db['otrs']['database'] = 'otrs';
$db['otrs']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['otrs']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['otrs']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['otrs']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['otrs']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['otrs']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['otrs']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['otrs']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['otrs']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['otrs']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['otrs']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

If you need more info, just let me know.

Thank you very much!

Comment: How are you trying to connect?

Comment: Hi, I just edited my post. Codeigniter should do the connection with these parameters.

Comment: I would change to the following `$db['otrs']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';`

Comment: Check if [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/old-client.html) is of any help to you.

Comment: This documentation is useful, but for those who have write access to the database. I have read only access.

Answer (score 0):

1/ - Did you check that the database accept external connexions (<> localhost) ? 
2/ - Did you check that your MySQL version is compatible with CodeIgniter ?

Pascal

Comment: Hello,
Yes, the database accepts external connections. I tested it using MySql Workbench with the option disable secure auth selected.
About the MySql version being compatible with codeigniter, yes, that's compatible. The version I'm using is 5.0 and Codeigniter accepts +4.1. Thanks!